# How to zoom towards mouse position in 2D in MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, zooming, monogame

I have the following Camera class:

```
public Vector2 Position { get; set; } = Vector2.Zero;
public float Rotation { get; set; } = 0.0f;
public float Zoom
{
    get
    {
        // Negative zoom will flip the image
        if (_zoom < 0.1f)
        {
            _zoom = 0.1f;
        }
        return _zoom;
    }
    set
    {
        _zoom = value;
        // Negative zoom will flip the image
        if (_zoom < 0.1f)
        {
            _zoom = 0.1f;
        }
    }
}

public Matrix Transform(Viewport viewport)
{
    int viewportWidth = viewport.Width;
    int viewportHeight = viewport.Height;

    return
        Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Position.X - viewportWidth / 2, -Position.Y - viewportHeight / 2, 0)) * // Translation Matrix
        Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) * // Rotation Matrix
        Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 1)) * // Scale Matrix
        Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(viewportWidth / 2, viewportHeight / 2, 0)); // Origin/Offset Matrix
}

public void Move(Vector2 amount)
{
    Position += amount;
}
```

And an `Update()` method that checks user input from keyboard and mouse to the certain things, e.g. move, rotate, zoom.

### The Problem

As can be seen from my Transform Matrix, when I'm zooming in/out (increment or decrement `_zoom`), I'm zooming towards a fixed origin point - the center of my screen.

How can I make it so when it zooms towards the mouse cursor?

I read a few answers to similar questions, but I couldn't implement it for my camera. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apply another Translation before the Scale to center the scaling on the Mouse Point.

```
public Matrix Transform(Viewport viewport)
{
    int viewportWidth = viewport.Width;
    int viewportHeight = viewport.Height;

    return
        Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Position.X - viewportWidth / 2, -Position.Y - viewportHeight / 2, 0)) * // Translation Matrix
        Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) * // Rotation Matrix
        Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-mouseState.X - viewportWidth / 2, -mouseState.Y - viewportHeight / 2, 0)) * //Mouse Translation Matrix
        Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 1)) * // Scale Matrix
        Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(viewportWidth / 2, viewportHeight / 2, 0)); // Origin/Offset Matrix
}
```